# How to generate PDF from HTML in Meteor 1.4.4.2 and 1.5 at server side

Tags: meteor

I am facing problems while creating a PDF from HTML in Meteor 1.4.4.2 and 1.5 which is latest version till date.

I want to know how to create a PDF from HTML at server side?

Comment: I have tried this article which helps you with generating pdf with PhantomJS and meteor. Check it out, it's very nicely put together. https://medium.com/@ryanswapp/getting-started-with-meteor-and-react-d411a87a1674

Comment: That post is outdated. I have completed with changes. i will update my post soon with correct procedure as I have wasted entire day to do it successfully. This shall help to other folks in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the steps to generate PDF from HTML Template using Meteor 1.4.4.2

1. Kindly goto **`PROJECT/.meteor/packages`** file and add packages as below

   ```
   meteorhacks:ssr
   bryanmorgan:webshot
   ```
2. Make sure whichever html page you want to convert to pdf must be present at location `PROJECT/private` as per Meteor 1.4.4.2 guidelines. In this example, the file name is `app_clientagreement.html` (file is simple html).
3. We will now create a method at server side to generate PDF. The file is at location `PROJECT\imports\startup\server\methods.js` (make sure you import the `method.js` file inside `PROJECT\imports\startup\server\index.js` as `import './methods.js'`). Inside methods.js write below code

   ```
   import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
   import { SSR, Template } from 'meteor/meteorhacks:ssr';

   Meteor.methods({
       'generate_pdf'(){

       var fs      = Npm.require('fs');
       var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
       var fut = new Future();
       var fileName = "pokemon-report.pdf";

       SSR.compileTemplate('agreement', Assets.getText('app_clientagreement.html'));
       var html_string = SSR.render('agreement');

       var options = {
             "paperSize": {
                 "format": "Letter",
                 "orientation": "portrait",
                 "margin": "1cm"
             },
             siteType: 'html'
       };

         webshot(html_string, fileName, options, function(err) {
             fs.readFile(fileName, function (err, data) {
                 if (err) {
                     return console.log(err);
                 }
                 fs.unlinkSync(fileName);
                 fut.return(data);
             });
         });

         let pdfData = fut.wait();
         let base64String = new Buffer(pdfData).toString('base64');

         return base64String;
     }
   });
   ```
4. To call this method in Template, for ease to get auto-called, I am calling it when a template is rendered. The code is below,

   ```
   Template.App_Agreement.onRendered(function(){
         Meteor.call('generate_pdf', function(err, res) {
           if (err) {
                console.error(err);
           } else if (res) {
                window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + res);
           }
         });
   });
   ```

When you call above template (which is 'App_Agreement'), a new tab is opened and a PDF is rendered.

Comment: I like your approach but with it I run into error Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'pokemon-report.pdf'..any idea where to place file or allow to edit?

Comment: you can read point no. 2 above in my answer. It says `Project/private` directory. btw the `pokemon-report.pdf` is generated, not stored anywhere. So, a new tab is opened and a PDF with that name is rendered.

Comment: yeah but I get error for pdf not html, so it said it can't read pdf file

Comment: Kindly show us stack trace atleast to assist you further.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vaske/c658813f4bf21f93998d4049d729b981 only one difference is that I send html as string do not use existing file, but that's fine